# Creating war file

Tags: java, linux, ant, war

I have extracted existing WAR file contents and modified few images. Now I have to re-create it to WAR file again using the extracted code from original war file.

I am working on linux.

Any idea how can we re-create war file.

Thanks

--Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the java jar command line utility to create the war file again:

```
jar -cvf yourwar.war updatedContentsdir
```

Learn more here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: Okay I got war file but the arrangement of strings has been changed as compared to orignal war file. Is it normal bahvior ?